# How to prove this vector direction angle identity?

Tags: vectors

How do I go about proving this: $\cos⁡^2α+\cos⁡^2β+\cos⁡^2γ=1$?

It's so different from normal trig proof, because the angles are not the same and everything is $\cos$. What steps should I take to arrive at the answer? Just a hint is fine too.

Comment: What are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$?

Comment: you should indicate that they are directional angles

Comment: sorry i have  used $\theta$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionCosine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we have  $cos(\alpha)=x/\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

$cos(\beta)=y/\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

and    $cos(\theta)=z/\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

then it would be  clear  if what is result

$(cos(\alpha))^2+(cos(\beta))^2+(cos(\theta))^2$
additional information

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine

Comment: My internet disappeared for a few hours, so I figured it out myself in the meantime. This is the same method I found myself.